# Use same zerolog setup in whole application

Tags: go, logging

I'm developing a Go application with self-developed package and i decided to use [`zerolog`](https://github.com/rs/zerolog) to log. Into init file I initialise a zerolog logger to save log into **multiple output**, but how can I use that setup into all packages developed? Are there some best practices? Is it possible use that setup without passing logger to packages every times?

Comment: Do you mean this [zerolog](https://github.com/rs/zerolog) ?

Comment: Yes, that is the module i'm using. I forgot to add reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare `Logger` in a different package called `logger` or something and use logger referring it in all packages

```
 package logger
 
 import (
    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
    "os"
 )
 
 var Logger zerolog.Logger
 
 func InitLog()  {
    consoleWriter := zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stdout}
    multi := zerolog.MultiLevelWriter(consoleWriter, os.Stdout)
    Logger = zerolog.New(multi).With().Timestamp().Logger()
 }
```

Declare `Logger` in logger package. Initialise Logger when booting the project and use it like below.

```
 package main
 
 import "myapp/logger"
 
 func main() {
    logger.InitLog()
    logger.Logger.Info().Msg("Hello, Main!")
 }
```